# Extracting Pages Based on Matching Strings in Acrobat Pro DC Java Script

Tags: javascript, pdf, extract, acrobat

I need to extract pages from a PDF document with matching strings i.e. Acrobat create a new file of all pages where it finds strings that I have in CSV or xlsx file

[This is a sample PDF file](https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/1/1/D112C308-C3DC-462B-AB8C-9E92C60A3D25/SystemUsersGuide.pdf) from which I only need pages having following two strings...

1. macros
2. salesperson

I found following code while googling around but it searches only one string and creates a new file of pages matching that string. While I need to search multiple strings and need only one file. Any ideas please...

```js
// Iterates over all pages and find a given string and extracts all 
// pages on which that string is found to a new file.

var pageArray = [];

var stringToSearchFor = "Test";

for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) {
    // iterate over all words
    for (var n = 0; n < this.getPageNumWords(p); n++) {
        if (this.getPageNthWord(p, n) == stringToSearchFor) {
            pageArray.push(p);
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (pageArray.length > 0) {
    // extract all pages that contain the string into a new document
    var d = app.newDoc();    // this will add a blank page - we need to remove that once we are done
    for (var n = 0; n < pageArray.length; n++) {
        d.insertPages( {
            nPage: d.numPages-1,
            cPath: this.path,
            nStart: pageArray[n],
            nEnd: pageArray[n],
        } );
    }

    // remove the first page
    d.deletePages(0);
    
}
```

I assume that some code will be added to load CSV/XLSX file and a FOR/WHILE loop to search all strings in that PDF file and storing their page numbers and then creating a new file with all these page numbers.

Comment: Link to another reference that I found...
https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/extract-pdf-pages-based-on-content/td-p/7543610?page=1

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this question [here](https://acrobatusers.com/actions-exchange/). In this website, [I downloaded this Adobe Action file](https://acrobatusers.com/assets/uploads/actions/find_highlight_and_extract.sequ) which do what I described above. It do one thing extra which is highlighting the text that it find in file which do not bother me.